# Tag buffers according to project

Tags: buffers

Is there an Emacs package that can help organize buffers into projects? I commonly work on many projects, but I only have one Emacs instance open (with hundreds of buffers). It would be nice if I could easily organize the buffers into projects (using for example a tag associated with each buffer; the tag name could for example be the name of the project that the buffer belongs to).

I could think of some tasks that could be performed by this package:

- Search through buffers of a given project
- List buffers of a given project
- Delete buffers of a given project,

and so on..

Comment: what about [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile)?

Comment: In addition to `projectile`, check out [`ibuffer`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode) and, to use both, [`ibuffer-projectile`](https://github.com/purcell/ibuffer-projectile).

Comment: @Nsukami_ Do you want to make this an answer with brief introduction of how to use projectile to do stuff that Håkon wants? As Dan said, ibuffer-projectile is super-awesome!

Comment: @kaushalmaudi sure, give me five seconds ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing is to make sure projectile is installed, you can install projectile using the MELPA repository. Then, you should ensure that projectile-mode is activated: `M-x projectile-mode`.

Projectile identify the root project using the `.git` directory or if you're not using git, you can put a `.projectile` file in the project root.

> Search through buffers of a given project

`C-c p s s`, to runs ag on the project. Requires the presence of ag.el

`C-c p o`, to run `multi-occur` on all project buffers currently open

> List buffers of a given project

`C-c p b`, to display a list of all project buffers currently open.

> Delete buffers of a given project

`C-c p k`, to kill all project buffers

Courtesy of [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile#interactive-commands) github page ;)

---

Also,

As stated by Dan in the comments, you can also use [ibuffer mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode) and [ibuffer-projectile](https://github.com/purcell/ibuffer-projectile), to group buffers by projectile project.

Hope this will help.

Comment: FWIW you can use ibuffer's grouping facilities without projectile. You can configure your groups manually (probably filtering by file path), and you can easily save/load/update your group configuration(s) whenever necessary.

Comment: @phils never really played with ibuffer. Should I edit my answer, to add the precision?

Comment: I think your answer is fine as it is -- it's specifically about Projectile, so it makes sense to suggest using `ibuffer-projectile` as well. Give `M-x ibuffer` a try, though; it's nice.

Comment: @phils Ok, I'll give `M-x ibuffer` a try, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can [*tag bookmarks*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags). And you can bookmark non-file buffers as well as file and directory (Dired) buffers.

So yes, you can use this feature to tag projects and project components of various sorts.

Tags are arbitrary *strings*, by default (including spaces, newline chars, etc). But a tag can also be an association of such a name with a Lisp value. In other words, a tag can act just like an object attribute or property: it can be a [*name/value pair*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#TagsAsAttributes).

Different projects or project states (e.g. workflow, releases) can have different tags for the same sets of files.

There are other project-related **Bookmark+** features, besides tags, and which complement the use of tags. Predefined bookmark types that are particularly useful for project management include Dired, Dired tree, bookmark-list, bookmark-file, and desktop bookmarks. Use these, for example, to switch among projects. And you can easily define your own type-specific bookmark "jump" command for any set of bookmarks (e.g., the files that make up a project).